# High memory consumption when returning a byte array from function

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to download a 10MB file and store it as an array for further processing.

Everything seems fine when using a direct call to `(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadData("<url>")`. But if I wrap it inside a function and return the result of the call to [`WebClient::DownloadData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloaddata) memory footprint increases to around 500mb.

The function that I use:

```
function My-Download {
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $True, Position = 1)] [String] $UrlCode
    )
    (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadData($UrlCode)
}
$x = My-Download("https://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/file_example_MP4_1280_10MG.mp4")
```

The reason I wrapped it inside of the function is that I also do additional processing on the data before returning it but even this small example illustrates the problem.

Calling `$x = (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadData("https://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/file_example_MP4_1280_10MG.mp4")` results in 83MB:

[image: direct call memory consumption]

Calling the above function results in 500MB:

[image: wrapper function memory consumption]

What is the reason for such a high memory usage and what can I do to optimize it?

Powershell version:

```
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      17134  407
```

Comment: Don't use the brackets when you call the function. Instead, use a single space character. `$x = My-Download "https://..."`. Also, the first index for parameter position is 0, not 1.

Comment: That doesn't seem to solve the problem.

Comment: `(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadData($UrlCode)` -> `,(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadData($UrlCode)`

Comment: Note the comma at the start.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked! What does the comma mean and what happens without the comma?

Comment: @hurlenko - the comma operator in that location wraps an array around the item to the right. that causes the "unroll collections" feature of PoSh to unroll the **_outer_** collection while NOT unrolling the inner one. apparently breaking the collection into parts to pass along is where the memory use came from. ///// i would not have even thot to look into that ... [*grin*]

Comment: @hurlenko - you are most welcome! glad to help a tad ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[System.Net.WebClient]` type's `.DownloadData()` method returns a byte array (`[byte[]]`).

- **If you assign the output from a call to that method to a variable *directly***, the **variable receives that byte array *as-is***.
- By contrast, **if a call to that method is used to produce *implicit output* from a *function***, the `[byte[]]` **array's elements are *sent to the pipeline, one by one*** (byte by byte).
  The design intent behind the pipeline is to enable *streaming*, *object-by-object* processing rather than collect-all-result-first behavior, which trades execution speed for memory-throttling, one-by-one, as-output-becomes-available processing.

Assigning the *function's* output to a variable then causes PowerShell to *implicitly collect the individual output objects* (bytes in this case) in a regular `[object[]]` array.

In other words: the original `[byte[]]` array was first *enumerated*, only to be collected later in *another* array, albeit an `[object[]]`-typed one - that is obviously unnecessary and inefficient in your scenario.

There are **two ways to opt out of this implicit enumeration**:

- Instead of *implicit* output, you can use a ***conceptually explicit* `Write-Output -NoEnumerate`** call in order to suppress the enumeration of an output array (collection):

  ```bash
  Write-Output -NoEnumerate (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadData($UrlCode)
  ```
- A more obscure, but ***more concise and faster* alternative** is to combine implicit output with an **auxiliary *single-element wrapper array***, which causes PowerShell to enumerate the wrapper array only, passing the wrapped array through, as [PetSerAl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4003407/petseral) suggests in a comment on the question:

  ```bash
  , (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadData($UrlCode)`
  ```

  - `,` is PowerShell's array-construction operator (the ["comma operator"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-6#comma-operator-)), and in its *unary* form it wraps the RHS in a single-element array (of type `[object[]]`).