# Controlling the type returned by a Function in PowerShell

Tags: arrays, .net, wpf, powershell, return

So, I'm trying to create a GUI for a search application using a WPF form.  My form has a TextBox and ComboBox for input, and the contents are applied as a filter every time the change events fire.  `$var_SearchRegion` is my ComboBox, `$var_SearchFor` is my TextBox, and `$var_DGDisplay` is my DataGrid for the return data.

In order to set the filter, I have created a basic function. I know there are cleaner ways to do this than an If Then ElseIf tree, but this was quick and it works.  The function looks like this:

```
Function GetFilteredItems
{
    $RSelect = $var_SearchRegion.SelectedValue.Content
    $PF = $var_SearchFor.Text
    $RF = If ($RSelect -eq 'All Regions') {''} Else {$RSelect}
    If ($PF -eq '' -and $RF -eq '')
    {
        $DPST
    }
    ElseIf ($PF -eq '')
    {
        $DPST | ? {$_.Region -eq $RF}
    }
    ElseIf ($RF -eq '')
    {
        $DPST | ? {$_.FilePath -like "*$PF*"}
    }
    Else
    {
        $DPST | ? {$_.Region -eq $RF -and $_.FilePath -like "*$PF*"}
    }
}
```

The issue happens when the filter reduces the dataset to exactly one entry and returns it.  I have had this problem before with PowerShell using .NET methods, and I am assuming the type changes from [Array] of "something" to just "something", and that is causing issues with the WPF objects.

Here is an example of the event handler code which is causing problems when the filter gets my return set down to 1 item:

```
$var_SearchFor.Add_TextChanged({
    $var_DGDisplay.ItemsSource = GetFilteredItems
    $var_DGDisplay.Refresh
})
```

When `GetFilteredItems` returns 1 item, I get this error:

```
Exception setting "ItemsSource": "Cannot convert the "@{Region=SW; 
FilePath=\\server\share\folder\file.ext}" value of type 
"Deserialized.System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject" to type "System.Collections.IEnumerable"."
At C:\Users\Matthew\GUITest.ps1:90 char:5
+     $var_DGDisplay.ItemsSource = GetFilteredItems
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], SetValueInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExceptionWhenSetting
```

I can easily "fix" this problem by wrapping the function call and explicitly converting to an [array] type, like this:

```
$var_SearchFor.Add_TextChanged({
    $var_DGDisplay.ItemsSource = [array](GetFilteredItems)
    $var_DGDisplay.Refresh
})
```

But it feels backwards to have to do this.  I should be able to fix this inside the function somehow.  However, wrapping the output lines of the function (in 4 places) with the same `[array]()` did not do the trick.  I found some information on PowerShell Advanced Functions, where I could use the syntax `[OutputType([Array])]` to designate the output type, but even though I verified I was getting `System.Array` as my output type using `(Get-Command GetFilteredItems).OutputType`, it would still fail with the same error.

TL;DR - Is there a way to avoid having to wrap my function call with `[array]()` and still make it work with my WPF DataGrid control's ItemSource Property?

Comment: I do this all the time because PowerShell under-the-covers often uses assignment to create the return object e.g.:  $return = Cmd.  If the results of the command are an array, it'll return as such.  If it's only ONE item, it'll return as a variable of type, whatever the object is.  To fix this I always use:  $return = @(Cmd)

Comment: @thepip3r, while you're correct in terms of the _net effect_, that's not quite how it works under the covers - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/60020105/45375

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- PowerShell by default *enumerates* collections that you output from a function (whether you output them implicitly or via a `return` statement)

  - To prevent that, use `Write-Output -NoEnumerate` or, more simply and efficiently (but more obscurely), wrap the output collection in a single-element aux. array (`, $collection`)  - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56926132/45375) for more information.
- In your case, you additionally need to make sure that what you're wrapping is *itself* always a collection, for which you can use `@()` or cast to `[array]`.

```
Function GetFilteredItems
{
    $RSelect = $var_SearchRegion.SelectedValue.Content
    $PF = $var_SearchFor.Text
    $RF = If ($RSelect -eq 'All Regions') {''} Else {$RSelect}

    # Collect your command's output in an array-typed variable ([object[]])
    [array] $result = 
      If ($PF -eq '' -and $RF -eq '')
      {
        $DPST
      }
      ElseIf ($PF -eq '')
      {
        $DPST | ? {$_.Region -eq $RF}
      }
      ElseIf ($RF -eq '')
      {
        $DPST | ? {$_.FilePath -like "*$PF*"}
      }
      Else
      {
        $DPST | ? {$_.Region -eq $RF -and $_.FilePath -like "*$PF*"}
      }

    # Output the array $result as-is, via an aux. wrapper array.
    , $result

}
```

Note: You don't strictly need the immediate `$result` variable; you could use `, @(if ...)` directly.

However, note that in neither case will the command's output *stream* (emit objects as they're being created), because the entire output must be *collected first*, before the aux. array can be constructed around it.

Comment: @Matthew, yes, it's basically the same, in that a function outputs to the pipeline, which makes what is being output subject to enumeration by default. To output a _single_ collection as a single object for the function _as a whole_, you'll have to use the  `End` block.

Comment: @Matthew :)  note that _everything_ is an object in .NET, including _collections_ (which happen to be objects that contain multiple other objects).

Comment: It is so easy to get answers that aren't quite right about PowerShell, just like it is so hard to get answers simple enough for a beginner in C++ or C#...not a whole lot of people truly understand what is going on behind the scenes in PowerShell...or even care about it.  I truly appreciate the detail and precision of your answers.  The answer you pointed thepip3r to (on my question above) was excellent, and cleared up a whole bunch about why to use `[array]$var=RHS` instead of `$var=@(RHS)`.  Very much appreciate your expertise.

Comment: I am glad to hear it, @Matthew, and I genuinely appreciate the nice feedback.