# How to merge multidimensional arrays of string in Powershell

Tags: arrays, string, powershell, multidimensional-array, array-merge

My code tries to merge multidimensional arrays of strings. I expect a function that returns an array with a single row and two columns, then call this function several times in a loop to produce an array with multiple lines and two columns.

I expected my code to reproduce the following results:

```
array1 row 0:  
col1 = blue
col2 = red
array1 row 1:
col1 = blue
col2 = red
array2 :
col1 = blue
col2 = red
col1 = blue
col2 = red
```

but it reproduces this instead:

```
array1 row  0
col1 = b
col2 = l
array1 row  1
col1 = b
col2 = l
array2 :
col1 = b
col2 = l
col1 = r
col2 = e
```

the code is:

```
<#
-----------------------
    |   0    |   1    |
-----------------------
| 0 | 'blue' | 'red' |
----------------------
| 1 | 'blue' | 'red' |
----------------------
#>

clear 

function myfunction(){
    return @(('blue','red'))
}

for ($row = 0; $row -lt 2; $row++){
    $array1 = myfunction

    Write-Host "array1 row " $row
    write-host "col1 =" ($array1[0][0])
    write-host "col2 =" ($array1[0][1])
    $array2 += $array1
}
write-host "array2 :"
write-host "col1 =" ($array2[0][0])
write-host "col2 =" ($array2[0][1])
write-host "col1 =" ($array2[1][0])
write-host "col2 =" ($array2[1][1])

Remove-Variable array1
Remove-Variable array2
```

Comment: `return @(('blue','red'))` -> `Write-Output (,@('blue','red')) -NoEnumerate`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, that worked! Thank you! Would you mind to explain the difference?

Comment: I hope the [linked duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60572132/45375) explains it.