# Powershell split an array into 5 arrays with equal length

Tags: arrays, powershell, powershell-3.0

Hello everyone hope you are all doing great! been searching but cannot get it right :( could it be possible for you to help me, please?
Need to split an array into 5 arrays with equal length, for example.

```
$MainArray = @(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11)
```

**Result:**

> array1 = 1,2,3
>
> array2 = 4,5
>
> array3 = 6,7
>
> array4 = 8,9
>
> array5 = 10,11

Each array as even as possible (order doesn't matters) has this and it splits but not as even as I would like to.

Currently, I have this (searched on the internet already)

```
function Split-Array {
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
    [Object] $inArray,
    [int]$parts
)
if ($inArray.Count -eq 1) { return $inArray }
$PartSize = [Math]::Ceiling($inArray.count / $parts)
$outArray = New-Object 'System.Collections.Generic.List[psobject]'
for ($i = 1; $i -le $parts; $i++) {
    $start = (($i - 1) * $PartSize)
    $end = (($i) * $PartSize) - 1
    if ($end -ge $inArray.count) {$end = $inArray.count - 1}
    $outArray.Add(@($inArray[$start..$end]))
}
return , $outArray
}
Split-array -inArray $MainArray -parts 5
```

This function splits the `$MainArray` into 5 arrays but not as even, the result is:

> array1 = 1,2,3
>
> array2 = 4,56
>
> array3 = 7,8,9
>
> array4 = 10,11
>
> array5 = 11

It even errors adding 11 into 2 arrays. My brain is burned at this moment, haha any help would be much appreciated. thanks!

Comment: First example is what I would want to achieve, get sub arrays as even as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To perform the element distribution as requested - with extra elements getting added to the *initial* output arrays - use the following.

```bash
function Split-Array {
  [CmdletBinding()]
  param(
    [object[]] $inArray,
    [int] $parts
  )
  [int] $partSize = [Math]::Floor($inArray.count / $parts)
  if ($partSize -eq 0) { throw "$parts sub-arrays requested, but the input array has only $($inArray.Count) elements." }
  $extraSize = $inArray.Count - $partSize * $parts
  $offset = 0
  foreach ($i in 1..$parts) {
    , $inArray[$offset..($offset + $partSize + [bool] $extraSize - 1)]
    $offset += $partSize + [bool] $extraSize
    if ($extraSize) { --$extraSize }
  }
}
```

Note:

- `[bool]` casts are used as a convenient shortcut to map *nonzero* values to `1` and zero to `0`, via using the resulting `[bool]` in the context of *calculations*.
- `..` - the [range operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#range-operator-) - is used to extract array slices from the input array, and also as a simple way to loop `$parts` times via a  [`foreach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Foreach) loop.
- `,` - the [array constructor operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#comma-operator-) - is used in its unary form to output each array slice *as a whole* - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56926132/45375) for an explanation.

Sample call, which uses [`ConvertTo-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json) to visualize the results:

```bash
Split-array -inArray (1..11) -parts 5 |
  ConvertTo-Json
```

Output (5 arrays with 2-3 elements each):

```bash
[
  [
    1,
    2,
    3
  ],
  [
    4,
    5
  ],
  [
    6,
    7
  ],
  [
    8,
    9
  ],
  [
    10,
    11
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you keep track of the arrays created, you should be able to get the results you're after:

```
Function Split-Array {
    Param(
        [object]$InputObject,
        [int]$Chunks
    )
    $track = 1
    while ($InputObject.Count -gt 0 -and $track -le $Chunks) {
        $chunk_size = [Math]::Min($InputObject.Count, [Math]::Ceiling($InputObject.Count / ($Chunks - $track + 1)))
        $chunk = $InputObject[0..($chunk_size - 1)]
        $InputObject = $InputObject[$chunk_size..($InputObject.Count - 1)]
        ,$chunk
        $track++
    }
}
```

The while loop starts, and it will keep executing as long as either of these conditions are met:

- `$array.Count -gt 0`: The count of elements in $array is greater than
  0. This means that there are still elements in $array that need to be split into separate arrays.
- `$arrayIndex -le $arrayCount`: The number of arrays created so far is
  less than or equal to `$arrayCount`. This means that you haven't
  created the desired number of arrays yet.

Answer (score 0):

My use-case for this is populating a hash with some unknown number of values from an array where I need a fixed size array value for the hash entries based on other criteria in my hash's values.
Lets say my array turns out to have 3422 elements and I need 100 per hash value plus whatever's left over for the last element added to the hash.
Then:
[Math]::Floor(3422/100) will give you the number of hash elements needed.
I use 3 counters: $i, $j and $k

For instance:

```
$myArray = (get-<whatever> |select -exp Name)
$mySizeLimit = 100
$total = $myArray.count
$buckets = [math]::Floor($total/$mySizeLimit)

$myWrkHash = @{}

$j = 0; $k = 0;

for ($i = 0; $i -LE $buckets; $i++) {
    if($i -LT $buckets) {
        $k = $j + ($mySizeLimit - 1)
        $myWrkHash.Add($i, $myArray[$j..$k])
        $j+=$mySizeLimit
    } elseif($i -EQ $buckets) {
        $k = $total - 1
        $myWrkHash.Add($i, $myArray[$j..$k])
    }
}
```